# Create another partition

Tags: hardware

I install elementary OS on desktop PC. My hard-disk was 500 GB but I make 70 GB Primary and 3.8 swap partition. I kept rest as unallocated.

Elementary OS is installed now I like to make second partition where I can put my data. I used GParted to make partition after booting OS but I could not save anything on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the partition, but you can't put files on it? You need to change the owner of the partition, like this:

```
sudo chown YOURNAME:YOURNAME /path/to/your/partition
```

For example, I had done this with my partition:

```
sudo chown aleksandar:aleksandar /media/aleksandar/4208aaf4-cd67-486b-a91a-bfe48ecb1792
```